# How to analyze an image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am stuck at a basic problem. I need to understand and analyze an image using matlab.
Here are few steps that I follow:
1. Get to know image properties(like image type(grayscale/rgb),colormap, max pixel intensity)
2. Study image histogram using imhist and check for particular features
3. Consider the area of interest for further processing.
4. ? 5. ? 6. ?

But the thing is that I really need to get in depth and try to find out if there is, suppose a guassian/normal distribution of intensity in pixels or the kind of noise that is present, whether I need to apply a laplacian filter etc.

Is this a trial and error process? 
If I'm following a goal based approach, say, detecting the optic disc in a retina image, I may need to do a literature survey before attempting to device an algorithm myself.
But I really need to analyze the image on my own and put some thought into it. 
Kindly help me with specific tutorials for image analysis.(i was able to find only function description and example code by googling this)

Comment: I find that in most cases you will proceed with your analysis based on a visual inspection of the image. If I was looking for a large dark shape, I would start with some simple thresholding and maybe move into segmentation techniques (region growing, perhaps?) If you are looking for something of a certain shape, maybe try morphological techniques (erosion, dilation, opening, closing). Does that help?

Comment: i'm looking at studying pixel intensities and figuring out if there are any patterns. visual inspection may not help in this case. i need to study an image even before bringing the goal/target into scope.

Comment: I think you can also start paying attention to the Signal Processing SE site http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ ...

Comment: If I was looking for a pattern (pattern meaning anything that occurs periodically), an Fourier Transform would be a nice place to start. Bright spots in the frequency domain correspond to periodic occurrences in the spatial domain.

Comment: @natan Thank you for the link. I was looking for something related to images.

Comment: @Chet I guess I need to follow a goal oriented approach. Fourier transform would be a good place to start. How do I represent image as a signal?

Comment: If you have read your image in at all, you already have. An image is a  signal, but unlike an audio signal which may look like, say a sine wave, an image is in two dimensions. This link should be helpful. http://matlabgeeks.com/tips-tutorials/how-to-do-a-2-d-fourier-transform-in-matlab/. If you are looking for a solid image processing  reference, you should check out Gonzales & Woods' Digital Image Processing text. There's great stuff online, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to analyze an image without a specific goal in mind, this is mainly because a computer works directly with low level details: pixel values in a 2D matrix. Humans, on the other hand, first see things at a high level: the image is a car, or a baby, or whatever.

A good starting place may be to analyze the statistical moments of an image, the mean, standard deviation, skewness, and higher order [moments](http://geography.uoregon.edu/geogr/topics/moments.htm). This is very useful particularly in texture analysis. Additionally, it may be better to calculate these properties locally (i.e. instead of getting the mean and standard deviation of the whole image, break it into an n by n grid of images) In either case, this will reduce the amount of data being dealt with. Alternatively, a Fast Fourier Transform will reveal any sort of periodic behavior in the image. A maximum in the frequency spectrum indicates that the spatial domain has some kind of periodic behavior. If you think noise may be a problem, a convolution filter is the way to go (gaussian mean, median, etc depending on the type of noise).

Most spatial techniques are only useful when you have some idea what you are looking for (or that you know there is actually something to look for), especially segmentation and morphological techniques.

Comment: Thank You Chet. This pretty much sums up what I had in mind. Heading back to basics with Woods & Gonzales!